# UI-router vs. NgRoute in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

If somebody has experience about ui router and ngroute in Angular2, please let me know about this. Which are pros and cons? Which is the best choice in a new project? If somebody found a useful link about this topic please linked it.

Answer (score 2):

If i would have to start a project today, probably i would use NgRoute.

UI-Router for angular 2 is still beta and documentation is incomplete and not clear enough. I really love the approach of managing state for routes as UI-Router does. It's make easy to rename routes when you need it and you could have states without urls.

NgRoute has change a lot since angular 1. You can achieve most of functionality of uiRouter and documentation is extensive with a lot of examples. I was able to migrate a project from UI-Router to NgRoute, i had to do it because an issue related to AOT (fixed in beta 4).

So, if is very short project, i would use NgRoute because UI-Router is still beta and documentation is poor.

Probably for long term project i would bet for UI-Router because my previous experiences with it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/

https://github.com/ui-router/ng2/issues/29

Comment: A lot has changed in last few months, what's your opinion now?